# Randomize x through y rows in a MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, random, mysqli

For example, how can I randomize rows ten through 20?
I only know how to randomize all rows using RANDR().
I am using PHP + MYSQLi.
Can someone explain me using MYSQL `RANDR()` ? I know it's not efficient.

Thanks,
Tom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a technique with SQL Server that might port to MYSQL. I assign a new GUID to each row, then sort on that.

Comment: This is more of a comment if I'm honest.. as it's not a definite answer.

Comment: I assign an id to each row. Then only select rows with the right id. Thanks